# line breaks in form element input value

Tags: html, forms, input, newline

I am trying to add line breaks (aka newlines) to values of the `input`-element. `&NewLine;`, `&#10;`, `&#13; &#10;` and `\n` aren't working; still everything is on one line.

I haven't found an answer to this question amongst other questions that solves my problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't actually think you can have line breaks for those types of form elements.  You may have to use a `<textarea>` tag which allows for literal line breaks:

```html
<textarea id="multiliner" name="multiliner">line1
line2
line3</textarea>
```

Comment: I was a little bit hasty and didn't mention that I was only able to work with elements that work with Clipboard.js and don't force a discontiguous error. However, both `<input>` and `<textarea>` work nicely with Clipboard.js, and `<textarea>` plays nicely with line break html entities. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 12):

The HTML `input` elements, type `text` or something similar (such as `email`) will deliberately strip off all line breaks, so that’s not going to work.

The only form element which will accept line breaks is the `textarea`.

Incidentally, Clipboard.js works by creating a dummy `textarea` element to do its magic.

Answer (score -2):

you can use div element and pass an attribute 'contenteditable="true"'

```
<div class="input-box" contenteditable="true">your inputs</div>

// css
.input-box {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use `<br>` for line breaks, see below

```
<input type="radio" name="table" value="info">Info<br>
```

Comment: I think the OP want inside the input, not outside