# In javascript, why when I use the <p> tag, there is result showed. But when I use the input text the result isn't showed as I expected

Tags: javascript, html

I write code to split the word and the result will be showed in separate lines.
The first code worked well:
    Click!

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function run() {
var str = "Hello";
var res = str.split("").join("<br/>");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

> Result:H
> e
> l
> l
> o

The problem is when I changed the p tag , it didn't work:

```
<button onclick="run()">Click!</button>

<input type="text" id="demo" name="demo" />

<script>
function run() {
var str = "Hello";
var res = str.split("").join("<br/>");
document.getElementById("demo").value = res;
}
</script>
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi, try to use other than a input, like textarea, You need to understand first what is an input

Comment: You can't split text (add HTML tags) into `input` element.

Comment: Hope this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743916/line-break-in-input-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't insert HTML inside `input`, but you can insert your text inside `textarea` and use `\n` (new row) character instead of `<br>`:

```js
function run() {
  var str = "Hello";
  var res = str.split("").join("\n");
  document.getElementById("demo").value = res;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="run()">Click!</button>
<textarea type="text" id="demo" name="demo"></textarea>
```

Comment: Someone else downvoted me, I'm just trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

An input can't have new lines within it. try using a textarea tag:

```
<button onclick="run()">Click!</button>

<textarea type="text" id="demo" name="demo"></textarea>

<script>
function run() {
var str = "Hello";
var res = str.split("").join("\n");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yrxzemm3/

Answer (score 2):

The `.value` of an `<input type="text">` element is parsed as plain text, not HTML. `"<br>"` set at `.value` should result in `"<br>"` being rendered as text at `.value`