# How to get line breaks entered into a HTML input text field?

Tags: javascript, html, textfield

I have an HTML form with 10 input fields of type text. I want users to be able to copy&paste one text with 10 lines into the first input field and then automatically place them into the 10 fields with Javascript. But the line breaks seem to be removed immediately, at least by Firefox. So when I get the value of the first field with Javascript, it has no line breaks anymore.

Is there a way to get the text with the line breaks? I can't use textareas because this would lead to other problems.

Comment: Best option is to use textarea. What other problems it may cause, can you be more specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [line breaks in form element input value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743916/line-breaks-in-form-element-input-value)

Comment: Can you please show us the relevant part of your JavaScript code?

Comment: Why can't you use a textarea? It might be easier to fix your "other problems".

Comment: I couldn't find a way to make a textarea behave exactly the same way as an input field and I had problems with the display of overflowing content, that is why I preferred a solution with input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, that's strange. But you can try this:

first of all, the html, you have textfields like so

```
<input classname="pastingBoxes" /> 
<input classname="pastingBoxes" />
<input classname="pastingBoxes" />
...
```

Then the JS

```
// first you get an array with all the inputs
let textfields = document.getElementsByClassName('pastingBoxes');

// so you assign input 0 a listener for the onpaste event
textfields[0].onpaste = function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   // this will split the data on newline, so you get a value per line
   let allValues = event.clipboardData.getData('Text').split(/\r?\n/)

   // then cycle trough it to assign the values:
   for(var i = 0; i < allValues.length; i++){
      textfields[i].value = allValues[i];
   }
};
```

and there you go! hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. I only had to add "event.preventDefault()", otherwise the original clipboard content would also be added to the field.

Comment: neat; I'll add that to my answer :D