# Why are escape sequences like `\n` not interpreted in a value= attribute of an <input> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone explain the reason why the following two portions of code have different outcome?

Result here is:

```
34rtyrtyrrtyr87 \n oiupoiuapgdaiuga
```

```js
var str = document.getElementById("custId").value

if (/\r|\n/.exec(str)) {
  console.log(str)
} else {
  console.log("not foundx")
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="custId" name="custId" value="34rtyrtyrrtyr87 \n 
oiupoiuapgdaiuga" autofocus> <br>
```

Result here is:

```
34rtyrtyrrtyr87
 oiupoiuapgdaiuga
```

```js
var str = "34rtyrtyrrtyr87 \n oiupoiuapgdaiuga"

if (/\r|\n/.exec(str)) {
  console.log(str)
} else {
  console.log("not foundx")
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="custId" name="custId" value="34rtyrtyrrtyr87 \n oiupoiuapgdaiuga" autofocus><br>
```

Tried to read the types, but both are strings.
Which kind of conversion is needed to make one behave like the other and vice versa?

Comment: HTML input element does not allow new lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743916/line-breaks-in-form-element-input-value you should use textarea for multiline text.

Comment: @Renato: These are `type="hidden"`.

Answer (score 3):

In a JavaScript string literal, `\n` is an [escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#string_literals) for a newline character. In an HTML quoted attribute value, `\n` is just the characters `\` and `n`.

If you wanted to insert a newline in HTML, you can just do that, sometimes at the expense of nice formatting:

```html
<input type="hidden" … value="34rtyrtyrrtyr87
oiupoiuapgdaiuga" …>
```

Or use a [character reference](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-charref):

```html
<input type="hidden" … value="34rtyrtyrrtyr87&#x0a;oiupoiuapgdaiuga" …>
```

```js
for (const input of document.getElementsByTagName('input')) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(input.value));
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" value="a\nb">
<input type="hidden" value="a
b">
<input type="hidden" value="a&#x0a;b">
```

Comment: Very useful. Thanks